# polymer does not work when i click on index.html directly

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer-1.0

I am using Dreamweaver for developing polymer app. all seems to be fine when i use F12 to preview my work in chrome. when i click on index.html directly, all the elements of polymer are missing.

[direct click on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs9a4.jpg)

[F12 in Dreamweaver (preview in chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upkxT.png)

what's the problem

Comment: You have to run it on server

Comment: i try to run on xampp, but it's the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install budo.

```
npm install budo -g
```

open the file (you need js file,you can create empty one)

```
budo index.js
```

and then go to you chrome

```
http://localhost:9966/
```

Comment: it show Cannot find module 'C:\Users\index.js' from 'C:\Users'
and i have created an empty js

Comment: I wrote open.. try without open.. budo index.js